# How implement View.IOnClickListener interface with Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm starting out in development with Xamarin on Visual Studio. I can not implement the `View.IOnClickListerner` interface. I would like to create my click management class separately.

When I implement it does not work. Nothing really happens at all.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, View.IOnClickListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Debugger.Log(0, "Message", "Start");
    }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        Debugger.Log(0, "Message", "Hello !");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the listener or it won't be called:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, View.IOnClickListener 
{ 
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle) 
    { 
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        Window.DecorView.SetOnClickListener(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What actually worked for me is setting the namespace for view.

```
using Android.Views;

[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```